# Combo Box control

Tags: mfc

I have a edit box control and list of numbers in combobox. If I enter a no. In edit box the same no. Should search in the combobox list and display it. I'm getting the selected no. with findstringexact() function but along with that all numbers are there in the list. I want to show only search no. and remaining numbers not be shown. Could any one help in this regard. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: What you are looking for is probably called autocomplete. Have you checked the codeproject articles for controls, like this one for example? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/187753/Extended-CComboBox